# Cropping multiple images in Photoshops to add logo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

I am working on a research project at the moment that requires me to use photoshop.

I have ten different images that are all screen grabs from google maps. I would like to crop all the images to remove any google elements such as logo, areial view in the corner.

I know how to use the crop tool but am just wondering how to make sure they are all same size - or cropped the same amount? as i would like to add some text to each image after cropping - these 'new' images will then be printed 6 X 4 size.

Any help would be great!

Comment: You do understand that technically you are not legally allowed to do this.

Comment: Hi @joojaa it's for a non-commercial (temporary) college project, I thought this would be covered under fair use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would paste each image to a layer in one psd-file then crop that file. Then use "export as..." on each layer (plus text).

Comment: Thanks Mikael!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Irfanview for this.

You can put all your photos into a folder, view one of them in irfanview, "T" for thumbnails for all photos, then select all, then "b" for batch processing, there's a button "advanced", inside you'll find "crop" and "add overlay text" and "add watermark image", and all of them have options of cut from where and cut how much ( in pixels).